# apply css class to input field in php

Tags: php, html, kohana, kohana-3

edit.php

```
<div class="detail1">
<?php echo Form::label("birth_date", "Date of Birth");  ?>
<?php echo Form::input("birth_date", $userdetails->birth_date,array('disabled' => 'disabled','class'=>'input-form)); ?>
</div>
```

The above is my code for date input field,i am trying to reduce the length of the text box,if i include any css class inside the label tag or input tag i am getting an syntax error.I am not able to add any css property to this field.How to apply css class to the above field.

Comment: Where's the syntax error? And what is the message?

Comment: <?php echo Form::input("birth_date", $userdetails->birth_date,array('disabled' => 'disabled'),class="date"); ?> 
</div>  ,i tried like in above the error is "ErrorException [ Parse Error ]: syntax error, unexpected T_CLASS"

Comment: Your syntax error probably occurs before this. I can't see anything wrong with your code.

Comment: You are missing a `'` next to `'input-form`

Comment: Typo related questions (and those identified simply as such) are off topic

Answer (score 2):

There is no 'special way' to add a class to whatever HTML Kohana generates. Kohana never checks whatever you wish to put as an HTML attribute. The following works for any element.

```
<?php echo Form::input("birth_date", $userdetails->birth_date, array(
    'disabled' => 'disabled',
    'class'    => 'Your class',
)); ?>
```

And seriously. [RTM](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/Form#input). This question should NOT EVER have to be asked.